# How to proof squareroot inequality by induction?

Tags: solution-verification, induction, proof-explanation

Hello so I'm making an exercise where you need to proof the following:
$$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leqq2\sqrt{n}\text{ with }n\in\mathbb{N}$$
But I seem to be stuck, this is what I have:

#### Base Case

Take $n$=1, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\leqq 2\sqrt{1}$, which is true

#### Induction case

take $k$ $\in\mathbb{N}$ and assume that: $$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\leqq2\sqrt{k}$$
add k+1, then:
$$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\leqq2\sqrt{k+1}$$
This is where I'm stuck, normally you could replace $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ with $2\sqrt{k}$ and then prove that the lefthand side equals the righthandside. But because its less than or equal I (at least I think)  can't replace it, so now I can't show if its less than or equal. So I can't seem to find a way to proof it by induction.

If you know the answer please share your wisdom

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $ 1 + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k}} \leq 2 \sqrt{k}$ implies that $ 1 + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 + k}} \leq 2 \sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 + k}} $ and that $2 \sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 + k}} = \frac{2 \sqrt{k(1+k)} +1}{ \sqrt{1+k}} $ which is bounded above by $ 2 \sqrt{k+1} $. To prove the last statement , take a look at $ 2 \sqrt{k(1+k)} +1  \leq 2(k+1) $ ...

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

We know $(\sqrt {k+1} - \sqrt k)^2 \gt 0$

$2k + 1 - 2 \sqrt {k+1} \sqrt k \gt 0$

$2(k + 1) - 2 \sqrt {k+1} \sqrt k \gt 1$

$2(\sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt k) \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt {k+1}}$

This should help.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 2\sqrt{k}$$
from the induction hypothesis. Add $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ on both sides to get
$$1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}.$$
Now, it only remains for you to show that
$$2\sqrt{k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{k+1}.$$
To do so, try to collect all the terms with a square-root on one side of the inequality, then square both sides. You should eventually get to something like $0 \leq 1$ which is trivially fulfilled.

Comment: Thank you very much